# Python - Создать массив 10 на 10 и заполнить его значениями по условию

Tags: python

Я не понимаю ошибки  list index out of range

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        mass[i][j] = r
mass
```

Comment: `mass = [[0]*10]*10`

Comment: @S.Nick Вы умножаете ссылки. Думаю, что стоило упомянуть, учитывая сколько на SO вопросов об этом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы обращаетесь к элементу массива, но он ещё не создан.
Создайте его с помощью спискового включения (или иным образом) перед циклом.

***Пример:***

```
n = 10

li = [[0]*n for _ in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        li[i][j] = i + j  # Some value

print(li)
```

***stdout***

```py
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]]
```

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ